Excel pulling information into CSV system
I have a question that I hope someone might be able to help with, I have an export from a system thats poor to say the least, it comes out into Excel as 3 columns, A is a reference, B is the persons details, C is a mix of email, phone, mobile and home numbers (with ; as delimiters)
the format of B is e: emailaddress m: mobilenumber h: housenumber
the house number and mobile sometimes has spaces etc. what I need to do is separate the C column which I can do with text to Column using ; delimiter but as its not alway e,m,h but could be h,e,m or others.
What I need is new Columns at the end or new tab that looks at the separate columns and just shows me Ref, Person, Mobile or Home
eg:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E
Column F




ITD123
Mr xyx
e: xyv@ao.com; h: 01274; m: 7845





MIN243
Mrs eye
h: 08774; m: 5485;e: kev@io.com;






using Text to Colums I get:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E
Column F




ITD123
Mr xyx
e: xyv@ao.com; h: 01274; m: 7845
e:xyv@ao.com
h: 01274
m: 7845


MIN243
Mrs eye
h: 08774; m: 5485;e: kev@io.com;
h: 08774
m: 5485
e: kev@io.com



Anyone know how I can do this without having to manually copy and paste?
I have tried Vlookup and IF but I am not a excel user. so I am a bit lost
Once I have this, I need to export the tab to CSV

Depending on where in the world you are located the function separator is ; or , you might need to change it.
The command :
FIND("½";SUBSTITUTE(A1;";";"½";2))

lets you find the nth occurrence of ";"
Assuming you have your data in A1:
ColD = TRIM(LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1)-1))
ColE = TRIM(MID(A1;FIND("½";SUBSTITUTE(A1;";";"½";1))+1;FIND("½";SUBSTITUTE(A1;";";"½";2))-FIND("½";SUBSTITUTE(A1;";";"½";1))-1 ))
ColF = TRIM(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("½";SUBSTITUTE(A1;";";"½";2))))


Here's one way of doing it, giving you a set order:
=SORT(TRIM(FILTER(TEXTSPLIT($C$75,";"),TEXTSPLIT($C$75,";")<>"")),,,TRUE)
The FILTER takes out empty cells (which was the case in your second row in the data sample); TEXTSPLIT then spills everything out, like text to columns does, but in a formula; TRIM removes spaces, and SORT then sorts it (the trim is needed so the sort will work).
Formula applied in column D. Drag down as needed.


If you are using Office 365 you can use TEXTSPLIT() function as mentioned by @Excellor. Otherwise, you can use:
In Column D:
=TRIM(RIGHT(C2, LEN(C2) - FIND(";", C2, FIND(";", C2) + 1)))
In Column E:
=MID(C2, FIND(";", C2) + 2, FIND(";", C2, FIND(";", C2) + 1) - FIND(";", C2) - 2)
And in Column F:
=TRIM(RIGHT(C2, LEN(C2) - FIND(";", C2, FIND(";", C2) + 1)))
